# How to wrap random(boost.random) library in a class?

Tags: c++, boost, random, wrapper

Currently i'm using boost for random, but there is a possibility i will switch it to other library or my own code(in some parts), so i want to wrap it inside a class and then when i need some random number (or something else) i will get it from this class instead of boost itself. The question is - how should i do it? Should i make this class a singleton or a static class or something else?
(I thought of a class because i need to seed only once but get functionality from different places and i dont want to seed in main.cpp)

P.S. If there is a way of doing it without a class, it will do as well.

Comment: Making a good PRNG is _hard_, so I recommend you stay with either boost.random or the new [C++11 random number library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making a regular class. This way the user can create an object, set some parameters and then query the values as in this example use case:

```
{
    YourRandomGenerator random;
    random.SetRange(0, 1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        CallUserFunction(random.Next());
}
```

This approach will make it possible to create different random generators for different distributions. Either through different classes (YourUniformRandomGenerator, YourGaussDistributedRandomGenerator, ...) or through parametrization methods (SetUniform, SetGauss, ...). If you want to seed only once (why would you want to do that?), all those generator classes could access the same static boost random generator.

Comment: But what if i need more than 1 random generator?(i.e. with different disitribution) I will make several classes like this? But then, how do i seed only once?

Comment: I have added the response to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Should i make this class a singleton or a static class or something else?

There are two canonical ways of doing it:

- An abstract class with a factory function.
- Pimpl idiom.

Both methods allow one to avoid exposing the implementation in a header file.

> If there is a way of doing it without a class, it will do as well.

You can get away with a non-inline function if there is no state that you have to keep around between calls.

Comment: You're talking about compilation firewalls, but what makes you think OP needs that? It might be overkill / bring unnecessary overhead to the solution.

Comment: @Fiktik Because the OP wants to be able to switch an implementation easily. This is what interfaces are for.